How to test rocksDB compactions in apache flink checkpoints
I have a flink pipeline running with some filters,maps,aggregator and windows operators. RocksDB backend with incremental checkpointing is enabled.
My checkpoint data size is growing gradually. I understand that once compaction starts check point size will reduce gradually. I want to test and prove this.
For that I configured the following values in my flink conf yaml.
rocksdb.compaction.level.max-size-level-base : 4096
rocksdb.compaction.level.target-file-size-base  : 2048
rocksdb.writebuffer.size : 2048

Though I see in task manager logs that these properties are recognized. Check point size is not reducing even after 4 MB. My initial check point size was ~400 KB.
Anything I am missing here? Do I need to enable any other properties?
I am not able to find if the rocksDB compaction happened or not. I want to enable rocks DB native metrics, so that I can monitor them in either flink web UI or a REST API? How to do that?
(I don't have any RichFunctions in my code to configure the metrics programmatically as told here https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/metrics/.)
(I understand that if check point size is not reducing there are some active state and we need to configure StateTTL. Before adding stateTTL i want to prove that compaction is not enough in my case)
Any help would really be appreciated.

For each RocksDB metric you wish to enable, set the corresponding config variable to true in your config. E.g.,
state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.estimate-live-data-size: true

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#rocksdb-native-metrics
For the config settings you mention, you need to include the complete name of each setting, and you should include units. E.g.,
state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.max-size-level-base: 4mb

Just because the settings are echoed into the task manager logs doesn't mean they were recognized and applied.

Thanks David for the reply. If I enable state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.estimate-live-data-size: true will I be able to see this in  flink web UI?

or rest api also fine. As i dont have any rich functions i can't add metrics in code. Looks like i need to configure externel systems to view them. Is it not possible to view the rocksdb native metrics in flink web ui or from rest api?

Today while testing i observed that some times check point size is reducing. I think it is because of compaction. But it was reducing like 500bytes, 200bytes like that then again started increasing. Today i made configured like below  state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.max-size-level-base : 2048 state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.target-file-size-base  : 1024 state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.size : 1024.
